# How do I make my code works so that it works in page load also? ngIf

Tags: angular

The following code works fine on button click, however it is not persisting the current state on page load. So what happens when I refresh , the values are resetting and nothing is happening

I want to keep the same state when I load the page/page refreshes also.

Please check the code below.

```
  showTab = 1;
  tabToggle(index){
    this.showTab =index;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  _showTab: number = 1;
  get showTab() {
    return parseInt(localStorage.getItem('showTab') ?? '1');
  }
  set showTab(value: number) {
    localStorage.setItem('showTab', value.toString());
    this._showTab = value;
  }
  tabToggle(index: number) {
    this.showTab = index;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried it and it didnt work for page load, however it is working for a button click.

Comment: again a problem. I have a new page created. On that page 3 buttons created. when I click on button 1 , it will redirect to page 1 and it should display page 1 tabs and if I click on page 2 I will be redirected to page2 and it should show only page 2 tabs. Any idea how to do it? Thanks

Comment: I suggest you read the angular document https://angular.io/docs

Comment: I have tried your code again in the freshly created page. Boom! it works without any issues. Perfect!